# Why is this email spam?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to troubleshoot why this is being marked as Spam and am running into a wall. I do have the spf record setup for websitedomain.com properly, but not sure if hostingdomain.com is throwing this off.

This is coming from a contact form on a wordpress site, using http://contactform7.com/docs/

```
    Delivered-To: info@websitedomain.com
    Received: by 10.205.23.130 with SMTP id ra2csp53286bkb;
            Fri, 20 Sep 2013 17:56:02 -0700 (PDT)
    X-Received: by 10.50.136.200 with SMTP id qc8mr4436670igb.52.1379724961891;
            Fri, 20 Sep 2013 17:56:01 -0700 (PDT)
    Return-Path: <serveruser@host4.hostdomain.com>
    Received: from host4.hostdomain.com (host4.hostdomain.com. [72.52.210.36])
            by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id 4si9708324ica.123.1969.12.31.16.00.00
            (version=TLSv1 cipher=RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
            Fri, 20 Sep 2013 17:56:01 -0700 (PDT)
    Received-SPF: pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of serveruser@host4.hostdomain.com designates 72.52.210.36 as permitted sender) client-ip=72.52.210.36;
    Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
           spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of serveruser@host4.hostdomain.com designates 72.52.210.36 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=serveruser@host4.hostdomain.com
    Received: from serveruser by host4.hostdomain.com with local (Exim 4.80.1)
        (envelope-from <serveruser@host4.hostdomain.com>)
        id 1VNBUP-0000p6-2a
        for info@websitedomain.com; Fri, 20 Sep 2013 20:56:01 -0400
    To: info@websitedomain.com
    Subject: Website contact from Customer
    Date: Sat, 21 Sep 2013 00:56:01 +0000
    From: Customer <contact.form@websitedomain.com>
    Message-ID: <78b6f35cdbec1e8760030b90bc791c9d@www.websitedomain.com>
    X-Priority: 3
    X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.4 (http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/)
    Reply-To: Customer <valid@email.com>
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
    X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
    X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - host4.hostdomain.com
    X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - websitedomain.com
    X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [505 505] / [47 12]
    X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - host4.hostdomain.com
    X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: host4.hostdomain.com: authenticated_id: serveruser/from_h
```